# Configuring Android Studio default module dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio

I don't want to have to go and write compile 'bla.bla.bla.bla' every single time I make a project, just to get Dagger and ButterKnifer and all the other stuff I use going, is there anyway I can have those compile statements be included in the build.gradle right away for any project I create?

Comment: So write it down to some common place and everytime just copy paste those in your project. The IDEs which we use don't remember our preferences/ choice , I guess

Comment: There isn't any way to do this? Wow, seems like such an obvious feature.